# Using more than one formatting option in powershell output

Tags: powershell-3.0

I am trying to format some output, and would like to control both the width and date formatting for an item.

```
foreach ($Item in ($dirs))   
{  
    # do some stuff here  
    "{0,-8} {1:d} {2,-16} {3, -32}" -f $Item.Mode, $Item.CreationTime, $Item.length, $Item.name
}
```

Is there a way to set the width of the 2nd column, in addition to how the DateTime is displayed?
Thanks for any hints....

Answer (score 0):

How do you want to define the width?  You may want to format the individual parts of the date using a format string.  See the format strings links for the date and time types category found on http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/txafckwd.aspx.

```
$date=Get-Date 
# 12-hour format (use lower case hh)
"{0:hh.mm.ss tt} " -f $date
# 24 hour time format (use upper case HH)
"{0:HH:mm:ss}" -f $date
# Date in "month year" format
"{0:MMMM yyyy}" -f $date
```

Or you could capture the string and format using alignment as in {index[,alignment][:formatString]}.

```
$a = "{0:d}" -f $Item.CreationTime
"****{0,-10}****" -f $a
```